# Deploy as api executable - stuck in a loop and won't deploy

Tags: google-apps-script

I've a handy script that formats a spreadsheet for me every morning via an API.

I had to update the script and it worked when I deployed in manually.

But the next day the API ran the old version of the script without my recent changes.

So I remembered I needed to "deploy as api executable".

When I select this option a little window appears and I click update.

Then the "deploy as api executable" window disappears momentarily and then reappears, with no error message.

I'm stuck in this loop unless I click "close" in the "deploy as api executable" window.

[image]

Comment: Not a answer: Delete the project and  create and deploy a new one

Comment: Have you tried changing the version?

Comment: @Kessy yes I've tried that to no avail.

Comment: @TheMaster I was trying to avoid this because I'll need to understand my own old  code :(

Comment: Have you tried copying the code and pasting it in another project? Can you share more details on the issue?